# C# call to C++ DLL function that requires an array of doubles and a struct as input

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers, dll

I need to call the following function from an old C++ DLL in my C# code. I can't edit the C++ code and this is all the info I have about that function:

> LoadMemDouble:
>
> ---
>
> Function:  uint PASCAL LoadMemDoubleAB(void far* lpobj,double far* lpy,TARHDR far* lptar)
>
> Purpose:   Load data into DLL from a passed structure of 64-bit 
>     floats. IMPORTANT - any passed arrays, data structures, etc. must be 
>     global as the DLL just maintains a pointer back to the array / structure.
>
> Arguments:
>
> - lpobj = Far pointer of prediction data structure;
> - lpy = Pointer of double type y value;
> - lptar = Pointer of data header. Note TARHDR was defined as:

```
typedef struct  {  dword   tarnpts;        //total number of data
                   double  tarffp;         //x value of first y data    
                   double  tarflp;         //x value of last y data
                   char    tarxtype;       //data type of x value 
                   char    tarytype;       //data type of y value 
                   uint    tarx;           //1=has x value 0=only y trace 
}TARHDR;
```

> !!tarx field must be set to zero;
>
> Returns:   0 or error code.

I imported the DLL in C# as follows:

```
[DllImport("plsiqp32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadMemDouble", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.None)]
public static extern int dLoadMemDouble(int handleCal, ref double dYvalues, ref DoubleHeader Header);
```

I built my structure in C# as follows:

```
public struct DoubleHeader
        {
            public int npts { get; set; }    
            public double FFP { get; set; }  
            public double FLP { get; set; }  
            public byte Xtype { get; set; }   
            public byte YType { get; set; }   
            public int Xtra { get; set; }    //this must be 0.
        }
```

Then:

```
 public DoubleHeader myHeader;
 public double[] myYvalues;

 myHeader = new DoubleHeader();

 myHeader.npts = npts;
 myHeader.FFP = FFP;
 myHeader.FLP = FLP;
 myHeader.XType= Xtype;
 myHeader.YType = Ytype;
 myHeader.Xtra = 0;

 myYvalues = dYvalues;

 int loadFromMemory;

 loadFromMemory = dLoadMemDouble(handleCal, ref myYvalues[0], ref myHeader);
```

I have no error message of any kind but it doesn't seems that this is working properly. I am suspecting there is an error in the way I am passing the double array and/or the structure. I am quite new to C# as well and I am stuck on this problem.

Only info I could find about this is in German here: http://microsoft.public.de.german.entwickler.dotnet.csharp.narkive.com/g9rTQP1U/c-dll-in-c-nutzen#post9
and its dated from 14 years ago... that's a really old DLL.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I the function using Windows Parameters list or C language parameter list?  I would be using IntPtr in c# for pointers.  IntPtr are 4 bytes which is equivalent to a c# Int to the code may look like it is working.  I would also make the return parameter an uint not an int to be the same as as the dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as jdweng suggested, the solution is to use a IntPtr for dMemDouble in C#.
 as follows:

```
[DllImport("plsiqp32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadMemDouble", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.None)]
public static extern uint dLoadMemDouble(int handleCal, IntPtr dYvalues, ref DoubleHeader Header);
```

Then:

```
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(double) * myYvalues.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(myYvalues, 0, p, myYvalues.Length);

loadFromMemory = dLoadMemDouble(handleCal, p, ref myHeader);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
```

Now that works nicely.
Thanks!